# bulk update posts of particular custom posttype

Tags: php, wordpress

i have more than 100 posts in my custom posttype - books
i have a custom field called link which is filled with data dynamically based on the fields.
on save post/publish/or updating each post it works perfectly by using a function which i have in functions.php
but its very very difficult to go into each and update so i m trying to get it to update all in bulk i have the code as follows.
It doesn't seem to be working i put it as a update.php and assigned it to a page  as a template so that when i open that page the code runs but it doesn't do anything.

```
<?php    
    $allposts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'books', 'numberposts' => -1,));    
    foreach ( $allposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
        if (!empty($post))
        {
            $booklist=get_field('booklist',$post);
            foreach ($booklist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
                if (!empty($post))
                {   
                    $bookname[] = strip_tags(get_field('bookname',$post)); 
                    $booklink[] = strip_tags(get_field('booklink',$post));                              
                }
            endforeach;
            wp_reset_postdata(); 

            $link = $booklink[0]."\".$bookname;
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'link', $link); 
        }
    endforeach;
    ?>
```

plus how do i get it to execute only when i want

Comment: when you want to use this code?

Comment: when i updateor change the booklinks i want the all previous posts to update too

Comment: Where did `$booklist` came from?

Comment: oops $bookname before foreach was $booklist...however it still doesn't work

Comment: any solution? anyone